# Reveal.js presentation full screen from JHipster

Tags: jhipster, reveal.js

I am trying to show a reveal.js presentation full screen from a JHipster single page app. The reveal.js example below works fine inside JHipster, it's just not full screen.  It can be made full screen by creating a second page, but given JHipster's design as a single page app things get messy with grunt and the production profile. I've also tried hiding the app menu bar and footer div elements but the reveal presentation still has padding around it. Ideally a full-screen view can configured.

Simple Reveal slide

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
      <section data-background="#faebd7">
        <h1>FULL SCREEN SLIDE</h1>
       </section>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem while keeping it a single page app. Previously I tried hiding elements of the page that prevented full-screen, but padding on the main div container was preventing full screen. The solution was to create a second ui-view div designed for full screen and hide all other div elements.

Solution:
1. Add "hidewhenfullscreen" class to the elements to hide.
2. Use javascript to show/hide elements
3. Add a second fullpage ui-view designed for full screen
4. Reference the fullpage ui-view from the controller

index.html

```
<div ng-show="{{ENV === 'dev'}}" class="development hidewhenfullscreen" ng-cloak=""></div>
<div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak="" class="hidewhenfullscreen"></div>
<div class="container hidewhenfullscreen">
    <div class="well" ui-view="content"></div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p translate="footer">This is your footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript to show/hide elements

```
<script>
    hide(document.querySelectorAll('.hidewhenfullscreen'));

    function hide (elements) {
        elements = elements.length ? elements : [elements];
        for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
            elements[index].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    function show (elements) {
        elements = elements.length ? elements : [elements];
        for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
            elements[index].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

JavaScript controller

```
    .state('show', {
        parent: '',
        url: '/show/{presentationName}',
        data: {
            authorities: [],  // none, wide open
            pageTitle: 'page title'
        },
        views: {
            'fullpage@': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/show/show.html',
                controller: 'ShowController'
            }
        }
    })
```

The page has a single small "Home" href that calls the show function. This way the user can go back and forth between the full-screen Reveal presentation and the standard jHipster view.

show.html

```
<div ng-show="{{ENV === 'dev'}}" class="development"></div>
<div class="miniMenu" id="miniMenu" ng-cloak="">
    <a href="/" onClick="show(document.querySelectorAll('.hidewhenfullscreen')); ">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
        <section data-background={{getBackgroundURI($index)}} ng-repeat="slide in slides track by $index">
            <div ng-bind-html="getContent($index)"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

For completeness, creating a second page can work but I don't think it is worth the added complexity. A two-page solution worked fine in the development profile, but the production profile had issues with caching shared css files, js files and fonts. With time and energy, I am sure the proper grunt configuration can be made to work, although the idea seems to counter the single page design concept. While in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Answer (score 0):

A second page is the way to go and below is a way to by-pass optimizations made by JHipster's production build.

JHipster's production build only optimizes files under `src/main/webapp/scripts` and `src/main/webapp/assets` directories. So, put your presentation files including revealjs under another folder (e.g. `src/main/webapp/slides`) and use a simple link from your app to load the presentation.

This is what is done for swagger-ui under `src/main/webapp/swagger-ui`

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  I'll continue down the second-page path. The challenge is that I still need access to ui.router, spring-security etc.

Comment: spring-security should not be a problem depending on which authentication type you use. Why do you need ui-router in your reveal.js presentation?

Comment: I tried the second-page approach but never got past the production profile issues. The swagger-ui example was not much help, it uses the main content ui-view and it is not shown in the production profile. The second-page also had production profile issues caching js, css and font files shared between pages.  Ui-router is a nice feature of JHipster. It allows the app to pull a specific Reveal presentation from the database based on URL path and parameters.

Comment: The swagger-ui index.html does not use ui-view, it is displayed in an iframe, only the iframe is in the ui-view, swagger-ui is disabled in prod by the SwaggerConfiguration class, just delete the @Profile here and it'll work. The production caching is configured in WebConfigurer, just tune it. You don't need angular-ui router at all for what you describe.